# TextField is not pushed up smoothly by keyboard, like in Whatsapp and Hangouts

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, iphone-softkeyboard

I'm trying to mimic the `UITextField`-keyboard relation in Whatsapp app.
As most of you know, there is a fixed `UITextField` at the bottom of the screen and keyboard comes up as you tap the `UITextField`. While keyboard is coming up, `UITextField` stick to the keyboard and they slide together very smoothly.

Read Apple's documentation pages which is about moving views under the keyboard several times.

***What I have tried so far:***

- **Listened to keyboard notifications**. I used both `setFrame:` and `setContentOffset:animated:` method within animation block. Didn't work as good as expected. The `UIViewAnimationCurve` value that keyboard animation has is 7, I couldn't find what it means as `UIViewAnimationCurve` has only 4 integer enum type. I think animation curve of keyboard animation is not provided to developers, I hope I'm wrong.
- **Using custom inputAccessoryView with lower z-index value**. I had two exact `UIViews`, one is fixed at the bottom and the other is custom `inputAccessoryView` that was going to hide beneath the fixed one since it has lower `zPosition` value. Therefore, user wasn't going to see the `inputAccessoryView` was coming up from outside of the screen but fixed view was being pushed up by keyboard. But no use, again. Changing `zPosition` value does not change anything.

At last, I thought Whatsapp might not be using system keyboard but a custom one. But if this is the case, it is a very very bad choice of design so that option is eliminated.

Anyone has an idea of how Whatsapp (or Hangouts) implemented that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing that turned out to be the correct way.

I should have listened to `keyboardWillShow`/`keyboardWillHide` notifications and `animateWithDuration:` as they are triggered. The point I missed was casting `UIViewAnimationCurve` into `UIViewAnimationOptionCurve` by shifting (<<16).

```
NSDictionary *notification = [aNotification userInfo];
UIViewAnimationOptions curveValue = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue] << 16;
...
[UIView animateWithDuration:{animation duration}
                      delay:0
                    options:curveValue
                 animations:^{
                     //animation code
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The value '7' is not a power of 2, so it's not a specific animation value, rather it could be the sum (or the bitwise or) of more than one animation values.
The solution (working for me) is:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:[userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
// set view frame here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Good luck :)